# How to best manage file either gz or not?

Tags: python-3.x, io, gzip, code-readability

Hi I wonder if there is a better way in terms of code readability and repetition.

I have a large file that do not fit in memory. The file is either compressed .gz or not.

If it is compressed I need to open it using gzip from standard lib.

I am not sure the code I ended up is the best way to deal with that situation.

```
import gzip
from Path import pathlib

def parse_open_file(openfile):
    """parse the content of the file"""
    return

def parse_file(file_: Path):
    if file.suffix == ".gz":
        with gzip.open(file_, 'rb') as f:
            parse_open_file(f)
    else:
        with open(file_, 'rb') as f:
            parse_open_file(f)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on the code review stack exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to assign either `open` or `gzip.open` to a variable, depending on file type, then use that as an 'alias' in the `with` statement.  For example:

```
if file.suffix == ".gz":
  myOpen = gzip.open
else:
  myOpen = open

with myOpen(file_, 'rb') as f:
  parse_open_file(f)
```

Comment: exactly was I was looking for thank you, did not know it was even possible